# Data resistance on Kafka topic on GCP pod failure

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka

I am planning to run Kafka on GCP (google cloud platform).

What I wonder is what happens to a data in Kafka topic when a GCP pod fails? By default a new pod will be created, but will the data in Kafka topic be lost? How can I avoid data loss in this situation?

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance :)

Best Regards,

Comment: Could you tell more about your scenario? You mention you want use on GCP and pods. You want to use Kubeadm on Google Compute Engine or you want to use Google Kubernetes Engine? You want to follow some specific guide? You could use Google Persistend Dist but you would need to use StorageClass with `Retain` policy.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka itself needs a solution for persistence, you will probably need a  cloud native storage solution. Create a storage class defining your storage requirements like replication factor, snapshot policy, and performance profile. Deploy Kafka as a StatefulSet on Kubernetes at a high level.

Answer (score 0):

Not understood exactly your purpose but in this case, you cannot guarantee Kafka's data resistance when pod fails/evicted. Maybe you should tried with native VM with Kafka installed and config that to be fully backed up (restorable anytime when disaster happen)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you need. It's quite a general question.

You have some ready Kafka deployments if you would use [MarketPlace](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace).

As you are asking for pods, I guess you want to use [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine). On the internet you can find many guides about using Kafka on Kubernetes.

For example you can refer [Kafka with Zookeeper on Portworx](https://docs.portworx.com/portworx-install-with-kubernetes/application-install-with-kubernetes/kafka-with-zookeeper/). In one of the steps you have [StorageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) yaml. In GKE default storageclass is set to `delete` but you can create a new `storageclass` with `reclaimPolicy: Retain` which will keep the disk in GCP after delete of pod.

In GCP you have also an option to create [disk snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots)

In addition to some best practice using Kafka on Kubernetes you can find [here](https://www.magalix.com/blog/kafka-on-kubernetes-and-deploying-best-practice).